# Fullscreen React Native on Android (with Modal)

Tags: android, modal-dialog, fullscreen, react-native

So I'm trying to run my React Native Android app in fullscreen, meaning no status bar, and no navigation bar at the bottom. I've added this to my MainActivity:

```
protected void goFullScreen()
{
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    this.goFullScreen();
    super.onStart();
}
```

SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY basically makes it so you can swipe from the top or bottom edge of the screen to bring them up, and then they go away again after a while.

This works well **until** I open any modal (using react-native-modal package, but it's based on the regular React Native Modal component). At that point both the status bar and the navigation bar appear. I'm not an Android dev, but I think that it basically creates a whole new window / activity / whateveritscalled for the dialog, which doesn't inherit the flags set for the main activity. Thinking it's here that this happens:

```
/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/modal/ReactModalHostView.java
```

Where it creates a new app.android.Dialog.

Anyway, I've been able to get rid of the status bar by changing the theme in styles.xml ([see here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/res/shell/values/styles.xml)):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.ReactNative.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

However, the navigation bar remains, which opens on top of my app's UI and doesn't even disappear after I close the dialog, so it's completely messed up.

Anyone have an idea how I might be able to get rid of that as well? Preferably without patching / rebuilding RN?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I also need to make a <Modal> full screen in android with transparency. (i also actually only want a `<Modal>` to be fullscreen, rest should have status bar)

Comment: Any luck solving this? Having the same issue

Comment: Back when I was looking into it, the best solution was to use this one: https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-immersive

(But that was a few months ago and the RN ecosystem moves quickly, so not sure if something better has come along or if that even still works.)

Comment: @TomBevelander did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @pushingbits did you find a better solution since?